# Normalization condition for distribution functions on subsets of $\mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

Motivation:
For the real line $\mathbb{R}$, there is a one-to-one correspondence between probability measures $\mu$ on $\mathbb{R}$ and equivalence classes $[F]$ of functions $F : \mathbb{R} \to [0,1]$
that are non-decreasing, right-continuous and $\lim_{x \to \infty} F(x) = 1$
with the equivalence relation $F \sim G$ defined by $F - G$ is constant.
Within the equivalence class $[F]$ there is a unique function $F$ satisfying the normalization condition $\lim_{x \to -\infty} F(x) = 0$. Such a function is called a distribution function.
The correspondence is given by $\mu \mapsto F(x) := \mu(-\infty, x]$ and $[F] \mapsto \mu(a, b] := F(b) - F(a)$ (which is well-defined).

For the Euclidean space $\mathbb{R}^n$ this is quite similar: probability measures $\mu$ on $\mathbb{R}^n$ are in one-to-one correspondence to equivalence classes $[F]$ of functions $F : \mathbb{R}^n \to [0,1]$ that have non-negative increments, are right-continuous and $F(x) \to 1$ as $\min_i x_i \to \infty$. Within each equivalence class there is a unique function $F$ that is normalized by the condition $F(x) \to 0$ as $\min_i x_i \to -\infty$. The correspondence is given by $\mu \mapsto F(x) := \mu(-\infty, x]$ and $[F] \mapsto \mu(a,b] := \Delta_a^b F$ (an alternating sum over the values $F(x)$ on the corners $x$ of the box $(a, b]$).

Problem: Now let $A \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ be an arbitrary subset. Can the above one-to-one correspondence for $\mathbb{R}^n$ be generalized to $A$, i.e. to a one-to-one correspondence between probability measures on $A$ and equivalence classes of certain functions $F : A \to [0,1]$ defined(!) on $A$?

Well, one can take a detour via $\mathbb{R}^n$ since any probability measure on $A$ can be extended to a probability measure on $\mathbb{R}^n$. In fact, this is quite natural since the inclusion mapping $i : A \to \mathbb{R}^n$ gives rise to the pushforward mapping $i_* : M(A) \to M(\mathbb{R}^n)$ (between Borel measures on $A$ and those on $\mathbb{R}^n$) by $\mu \mapsto i_*(\mu) =: \widehat{\mu}$ with $\widehat{\mu}(B) := \mu(B \cap A)$ for $B \in \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^n)$. In particular, a probability measure $\mu$ on $A$ can be represented by the distribution function $\widehat{F} : \mathbb{R}^n \to [0,1]$ corresponding to $\widehat{\mu}$. But $\widehat{F}$ is defined on all of $\mathbb{R}^n$! One can restrict $\widehat{F}$ to $A$, but this is often no the right way to go. For instance, consider $A = [0, \infty) \subseteq \mathbb{R}$. Then the Dirac measure $\mu = \delta_0$ gives rise to the distribution function $\widehat{F} : \mathbb{R} \to [0, 1]$, $\widehat{F}(x) = \delta_0(-\infty, x]$, so that $\widehat{F}(x) = 1$ for all $x \geq 0$. Therefore, $\widehat{F}|_A : A \to [0,1]$ is the constant function $1$. However, a constant function induces the zero measure (since it has no variation at all). In this setup, one rather usually defines a distribution function $F : [0, \infty) \to [0,1]$ corresponding to a probability measure $\mu$ on $[0, \infty)$ with the normalization condition $F(0) := 0$. In particular, the Dirac measure $\delta_0$ on $[0, \infty)$ is represented by the function $F : [0, \infty) \to [0,1]$ with $F(x) = 1$ for all $x > 0$ and $F(0) = 0$. In case of a closed interval $A \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ this is rather simple. But how does this generalize to arbitrary subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ yet to those of $\mathbb{R}^n$ (without taking the detour via an embedding into $\mathbb{R}^n$)? How can one describe a suitable normalization condition for distribution functions $F : A \to [0, 1]$?

[I honestly doubt that there is a simple solution, since the fact that we are given a subset(!) $A \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ just means from a category theoretical point of view, that we are in fact given an injective morphism, namely the inclusion mapping $i : A \to \mathbb{R}^n$, so that the surrounding space $\mathbb{R}^n$ is always available in this context.]

Comment: Probability distributions are a special case. More generally, measures can be represented as distributions of order $0$, and so as derivatives of functions of bounded variations. Perhaps the good keyword is Riesz representation theorem?

Comment: In higher dimension however, not all functions are gradients of other functions, and one has to precise the differential operators. For example one can use div and curl in dimension 3. Of course this is not a direct answer to your question but perhaps a good point of view to your reasoning